# Upgrading IIS web sever framework 2.0 to 3.5 considerations

Tags: asp.net, iis, frameworks, upgrade

i will be responcible for upgrading an IIS web server from the Microsoft .NET framework v2.0 to v3.5.

I am wondering if there is anything special i need to know or any caveats i should be aware of before proceding?

The site gets a fair number of hits per day and I will be taking it down and performing the upgrade at an off-peak time.

Aside from double clicking the installer is there anything i need to know?

Will the server need to be rebooted afterwards, does the installer handle all of the configuration changes? etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from 2.0 to 3.5 is largely seamless since everything still hits the 2.0 runtime. I can't recall a single configuration change I made (aside from running the installer) to our production servers when we upgraded.

If you have a test environment I would really suggest running your upgrade there before your production to make sure you're not going to break anything. If that's not an option, I would recommend reviewing the [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/a/e/9ae0f6cc-7032-408e-9ca7-989f9e4af4ec/dotnetreadme.htm) which contains some known installation issues and workarounds.